# Server URL changes to localhost URL when trying to navigate | Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, url, navigation

I have hosted my project on a server but when I try to navigate through the URL changes to localhost.
I am using base_url(); here.

`https://{server_url}/2017464/Pizza_Application/PizzaNow/index.php/Home`

When clicking on the navigation menu buttons it fetches the localhost URL. This issue is happening throughout my application. how do I resolve this?

`http://localhost/2017464/Pizza_Application/PizzaNow/index.php/Home`

**header.php view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light " style="background-color: white">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Home">
            <img src="<?PHP echo base_url();?>/assets/images/PizzaNow.png" width="100" height="100" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
            </a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Home">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item " style="padding-right: 8px; padding-left: 10px;">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Home/pizza_menu">PIZZA</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Home/side_menu">SIDES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Home/special_deals">SPECIAL</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Home/cart">CART</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
                    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Home/search" method = "post"class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="keyword" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" name="submit" value="SEARCH" >
                    </form>
                </li>
                <!--<li class="nav-item " style="padding-left: 400px;">
                    <a class="nav-link fa-user" href="<?php /*echo base_url();*/?>index.php/Home/account_details" id="myaccount" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="<?PHP /*echo base_url();*/?>/assets/images/user_icon.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">                     My Account
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item " style="padding-left: ;">
                    <a class="nav-link fa-user" href="<?php /*echo base_url();*/?>index.php/Login/logout" id="logout" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="<?PHP /*echo base_url();*/?>/assets/images/logout.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
                        Logout
                    </a>
                </li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this Issue, I had to change the CI project name and re-upload to the server. I hope uploading several times to the server with the same name confused the server.